Is it safe to heat Naoh under reflux in glass?
I just read a patent that called for 1000ml of 100% Naoh to be heated and stirred at 140 degrees Celsius for four hours in a round bottom flask. I re-read the patent and there are no acids being mixed with the Naoh.  I’ve always been told that concentrated Naoh and glass should never be mixed, let alone at 140 Celsius for four hours. Is this really doable while being safe? I imagine the glass cracking and causing a major horrific accident but this is what the patent really calls for. What am I missing?

100% NaOH?? Do you mean a highly concentrated aqueous solution of NaOH?

I think you misread it, or there was a typo... Either way you gotta link things!

The OP must have meant Noah, but it is not clear why should Noah be heated under reflux.

100% NaOH is solid at 140 Deg C. You may mean 50% as 100 g NaOH + 100 g (mL) of water.

This is the exact word for word patent: In two neck round bottom flask equipped with condenser 17.6 gms (0.10 moles) of result obtained from step 1, and 100 ml of 100% sodium hydroxide were added. The reaction mixture was heated up to 140° C. and 18.5 gms (0.1 moles) of any phenethyl halide was then added. The reaction mixture was stirred for 4 hrs. After the completion of the reaction, the reaction mixture was poured in the ice cooled h20.
Is this really doable in a glass flask? Also, although it’s says 100% Naoh I think Poutnik is correct: I think it’s probably 50% (100g Naoh + 100ml h20

Be aware that consistent mistyping of chemical element symbols means carelessness or ignorance. Neither of them is taken lightly by chemists.

If this is not a paper exercise, I suggest you try running the reaction on a small scale with 50% aq NaOH in a flask that is expendable.

100 % NaOH solution, probably weight per volume, so 100 g per 100 ml solution which is a saturated solution. this unit is still sometimes used but its not recomended since it causes confusion. I feel like the reaction with glass is still quite slow, don´t really expect to etch through but I´d be interested to hear of the results. Also the reaction with the reactants might be faster, which weakens the effect on the glass.

In graduate school, I had lab mates that did an elimination reaction using molten KOH (or maybe NaOH) in a pyrex round bottom flask.  The flask was only good for 2-3 reactions before it became thin enough to cause concern that it could break and had to be discarded.
